# Webclient response handler (both success & error) does not execute for empty response body

Tags: spring-webflux

Have an async REST API client implemented with OkHttp, works just fine.
Trying to convert it to WebClient out of curiosity, observing weird behaviour.

WebClient configuration is just this:

```
webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .defaultHeaders(headers -> headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
        org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(builder -> builder
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, timeout)))
    .build();
```

request code:

```
void getTokenWithWebClient(Consumer<Try<String>> callback) {
    webClient.post()
        .uri(url)
        .syncBody(new MyRequest())
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.value() != HttpStatus.OK.value(),
            rs -> rs.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body -> new IOException(String.format(
                "Response HTTP code is different from 200: %s, body: '%s'", rs.statusCode(), body))))
        .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
        .subscribe(rs -> callback.accept(Try.of(() -> validateResponse(Option.of(rs)))),
            ex -> callback.accept(Try.failure(ex)));
}
```

In the unit test, callback that is passed as an argument to this method, completes a Future, on which I wait. 
So, when I **run** the test in IDEA, and the request results in a response with empty body (content-length: 0), the lambdas in subscribe() never execute - verified using println debugging.

But when I **debug** the same test, even without any breakpoints set, it completes as expected and the lambdas are invoked depending on the result.

I do see this in the log:

```
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] Received last HTTP packet
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] USER_EVENT: [Handler Terminated]
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] Disposing context reactor.ipc.netty.channel.PooledClientContextHandler@3547abe3
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.channel.PooledClientContextHandler - Releasing channel: [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522]
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.resources.DefaultPoolResources - Released [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522], now 0 active connections
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] READ COMPLETE
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] READ COMPLETE
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] CLOSE
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] INACTIVE
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0xeffaded6, L:/127.0.0.1:49265 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:58522] UNREGISTERED
```

but then the Mono with my error gets stuck somewhere.

Running this on Windows 7, Oracle JDK8 x64, IDEA 2018.
Option/Try are vavr classes (io.vavr:vavr), not relevant for this case.
For unit tests, I mock the REST API in question using Ratpack.

Tried using exchange() instead of retrieve() and checking the status code in the subscribe() lambda, without onStatus() - with the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

long story short, `rs.bodyToMono(String.class).defaultIfEmpty("")` saved the day